# How can I see a page error in jMeter?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

How can I see an error in JMeter?

In other words, if a test fails, How is it possible to see the page returned with the error ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In our application we have a custom error page displaying a certain message. In JMeter we added a **Response Assertion** to the TestPlan (*Add > Assertions > Response Assertion*). We configured this assertion to have a pattern checking for this message (e.g. check for "error occurred" or whatever your error page shows).

Then we added a **View Results Tree** to the Thread Group (*Add > Listener > View Results Tree*) and configured it to display the errors only (check *Log/Display only Errors*). This result tree now captures all error pages along with their requests.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you set up your test, you will most likely get a 404, 401 or 500 error code from your server.

You can then use the access logs of the server (not jMeter) to see which page it was that returned the error.